# Moving to PreparedStatement from concatenating SQL string in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Suppose, I have a form and based on the  fields filled in in the form by the user, I create in Java code the SQL statement by using Java string and concatentaion of clauses like  "field1 = 'A' and field2 = 'B' and field3 = 'C'", etc. If the field is not filled in I just skip this part and not add it to my Java SQL string thus accepting any values in that field in database table. I'm justly told that concatenating SQL strings is a bad practice  and I should rather use PreparedStatement rather than direct executeQuery. How would I do it in such case without creating separate PreparedStatement for each combination of present fields in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, well done for moving away from concatenating strings with the field values.  You just saved yourself from a nasty SQL injection attack.

You want to use the same logic as before - the same set of `if` statements, and only add a clause to the SQL where the field is present.  You'll probably want a `StringBuilder` to build up the SQL and an `ArrayList<String>` to store the parameter values until you're ready to use them. You might end up with a whole lot of blocks that look something like this.

```
if (! field1Text.equals("")) {
    sql.append(" and field1 = ?");
    params.add(field1Text);
}
```

Then, at the end, after you've made your `PreparedStatement`, you'll iterate through the list of parameters, calling `setString` for each.

Comment: David, thanks a lot for the quick response and great advice. Still, it looks like a lot more work with tracking the position. But you are right, nowadays that every four-year old knows how to do SQL injection, we should be wary. And also I just simply cannot search for the last name like "O'Connor". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a framework like QueryDSL or JOOQ.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Actually I'm planning to do it in Android SQLite environment. Will those things work with it? At this point I don't even know if PreparedStatement will work with SQLite, but kind of hope it should.

Comment: In Android you should use a ContentProvider, and you can use a SQLiteQueryBuilder.

Comment: But if I create where clause in SQLIteQueryBuilder by concatentaiong my conditions with appendWhere() will it be immune to SQL injection and will it allow to have apostrophes in the search?

Comment: Strange, that appendWhere does not take care of these " and " situations; you have to invent the way to track if this is the first appended clause or not the first one. Perhaps, there is a better way, and I'm missing something.